# String list to Int List parsing

Tags: list, parsing, f#

I have a String lists which looks like this

```
String list = ["150";"350";"100"]
```

I am now trying to parse this into a int list so i can take the values and make calculations with them. The problem i have right now is im quite new to f# and not sure how to do this.
I was thinking of making a fold function which run a System.Int32.Parse on every value in a list

```
let listParser list = List.fold (fun listParser a -> (System.Int32.Parse a) :: intlist) list
```

This function gives me String list -> Int list, but when i run this function i get

```
stdin(105,12): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
int list    
but here has type
string -> string list
```

any better way of doing this? appreciating any form of help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[List.fold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353894.aspx) doesn't seem like the correct match for your requirement since it's a method that applies a function to each list element and accumulates the result as a single value, such as an average.

You could use [`List.map`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370378.aspx) though;

```
> let list = ["150";"350";"100"];;
> let listParser list = List.map System.Int32.Parse list;;
val listParser : list:string list -> int list

> listParser list;;
val it : int list = [150; 350; 100]
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for, is the [List.map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370378.aspx) function:

```
let list = ["150";"350";"100"] 
let listOfInts = List.map System.Int32.Parse list
```

Using a lambda, the second line would be

```
let listOfInts = List.map (fun a -> System.Int32.Parse a) list
```

but you don't need the lambda in this case.

It's a common practice to use the pipe forward operator when working with collections in F#, like so:

```
let listOfInts = list |> List.map System.Int32.Parse
```